# how to output the result to either console or on the page

Tags: javascript

Ok, embarrased to be asking such a basic question but here goes. And yes, I googled it, but for some reason the light bulb doesn't go off.

So, here's a sample code:

```
var name = "Oy Vey";

for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    return name[i];
};
```

How do I output that in the browser's console?

Or print out the results on a web page?

(yes, I know, basic question. please be kind)

Comment: use ```console.log(i)``` to print output in browser's

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: Why do you want "return" in loop? It will always return first element.

Comment: @Windchill, I didn't know that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Slai, thank you! (extra characters!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `return` statement in your looping you only get the first result of your iteration remember that. You can use `console.log()` or you can use html to render result, something like this:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>JavaScript output</h2>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var name = "Oy Vey";
    var leng_name = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        leng_name += i + 
"<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = leng_name;
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
return name[i];
```

To this line:

```
console.log(name[i]);
```

Comment: You forgot OP's second question, "Or print out the results on a web page?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) to write things to the console:

```
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    console.log(name[i]);
};
```

Another way to check values is to use [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), which will show the value you provide it in a dialog box:

```
if (name != 'bob') {
    alert("Access denied");
}
```

Showing the data in your page is more complicated. A couple of quick ways are by manipulating the DOM directly:

```
document.getElementById("myparagraph").innerHTML = name;
```

Or with JQuery:

```
$("#myparagraph").text(name);
```

Both of these methods rely on an element (with ID `myparagraph`, which you can change to whatever you like) which can hold the text. Ideally it would be a `<p>`, `<span>`, or heading.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `console.log(name[i])` to print in console from inside the array. for printing results on webpage you will need to do something like this:

```
var name = "Oy Vey";

for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    document.body.innerText += name[i] // print data in body
    console.log(name[i]); // print data in console
    // return name[i]; //  gives an error if not used in a function
};
```

you can also user `alert("dummy_string")` to alert the data.

Comment: it will actually give out an error if it is not used in an function. but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

in your case

```
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
    console.log(name[i]);
}
```

to put the output in current page check

```
getElementById
getElementsByTagName
getElementsByClassName
```

for more [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)